# JavaScript: Catch not hit on "Uncaught SyntaxError" [Chrome]

Tags: javascript, error-handling, console, try-catch, syntax-error

Can someone explain to me why an "Uncaught SyntaxError" isn't handled by a try/catch? Is it possible to gracefully handle this type of error so the rest of the JS runs?

For example:

```
try { response.write(;); }
catch(e) { console.log(e); }
```

This code throws a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" [Chrome] browser error instead of jumping to the catch and logging the error object. You get similar results in Firefox as well; a thrown error instead of handling it with the catch.

Answer (score 6):

A syntax error is not a run-time exception.  In order for your program to be able to throw and catch exceptions, it needs to be able to run.  In order to run, it needs to be javascript.  The above example is not valid javascript.  The interpreter gives up and prints an error when it sees the first invalid line and it never even gets to the "catch" line.

Comment: In order to catch errors occurring while using appendChild with a script module, I use a temporal window.onerror listener, that I wrap in a Promise.

Answer (score 5):

Well, since this is a syntax exception, it means that javascript parser failed to parse you code. Since browser failed to parse your code, it can not execute it. It does not even know about your try/catch block. try/catch block can only catch exception thrown as a result of code executing in context of the block.

Comment: Brilliantly explained. I wish someone could have explained this to me while I was learning JS.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a workaround for this.

```
try {
    Function('response.write(;);')
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Could be used for determining [es6 template string support](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings) this way:

```
var isEs6Template;
try {
    Function('``');
    isEs6Template = true;
} catch(e) {
    isEs6Template = false;
}

console.log('es6 template is', isEs6Template ? 'supported' : 'unsupported');
```